How to delete Finder Quick Actions?
I installed some software before, and it add a Quick Actions to my Finder.
How can I delete these Quick Actions?


If you have installed any additional Quick Actions, they will be in /Library/Services or ~/Library/Services.
The first six of those Quick Actions are part of the OS, and installed on every Mac. They cannot be deleted from the disk, but you should be able to un-check them, so that they won't show in the contextual menus.
It's also possible that Quick Actions are stored within the application bundle itself; in which case you will have to delete the app.
